# how does one pass the credentials from a Google Cloud Identity Access Management system to a compute VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I wish to use the Google cloud IAM ( identity access management) system for a new Google App Engine project. (Although it's not necessary to know, the front-end will be an angular JS, and the backend in Java.) However, once the user  logs into my app using his or her browser and is then authenticated via Google Cloud IAM, I need to know whether it's possible to pass this " authenticated credential" to a Google compute VM. If so, how? The reason why need to pass this "authenticated credential" is that I wish to use the gsutil ( or similar) functionality on a Google compute VM and I want to use the same username to ensure that the security profile carries through properly. (Specifically, I intend to use gsutil to communicate with Google cloud storage, but I intend to do this from a *Windows Server* compute engine VM.)

I've been reading on the Google computer VM and Google cloud IAM, and they all talk about being able to pass the "service account" token,  but there is no reference to how to pass a "authenticated user" credential  so that the gsutil  command that can access Google cloud storage on the Windows VM could use this authenticated user. (I want to avoid making the user authenticate both for my application as well as for the gsutil  program running within the compute engine Windows VM.)

Is this possible? If not, any suggestions/workarounds?

One idea I had, though ugly, is as follows: every time a Windows compute engine VM is requested, we would dynamically create a new Google service account which had the same permissions as the logged in IAM-authenticated user. Then, we would uses Google service account within the Windows compute VM to contact Google cloud storage. This solves the problem of ensuring that the same privileges are communicated, though it creates a slightly different problem in that all the logs that are generated for access to the file will be using this dummy service account instead of the real users name.